# Export phone application to computer?

Tags: apps, 8.1-update-1, nokia-lumia-930

So I have a Lumia 930 with WP8.1 Update 1.

I have an application installed on it that I would like to export (copy) to my PC. How can I do this?

Edit: For clarification, it's not a store app, I want to have the app and it's files for analysis on my PC, not for running it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract the contents of an app from your phone to your PC if you are not the developer of that app (otherwise you would at least be able to look at the Isolated Storage). If the app is in the Windows Phone Store you can download the .xap or .appx file from windowsphone.com.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I don't want to run the app on my PC, just have it there for further analysis. And the said app is not available in the store.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy an app as such from phone to pc. If you have a windows PC, go to windows store and download the app. To sync, you have to have an account. If you could tell us the app you want in your PC, further help can be extended.

Do you want the app in your PC because you may lose the app from phone while updating? I don't think apps gets deleted when the phone updates. Also, you can always install the app for free after the update.

Comment: Please see my edit. There is not backup feature that also copies applications, like in Android or iOS?

Comment: The Backup Feature only remembers what apps you have installed. It might also be able to restore the saved data from the cloud, but that depends on how the dev handles that data. Either way there's no way that I know of that you can directly access or copy that Information.